# Specifying the type of a function in a where clause

Tags: haskell, types, where-clause

I have the following Monad instance, based on the material in [these slides](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/16wi-cs240h/slides/iteratee-slides.html#(19)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

newtype Iter a = Iter { runIter :: Chunk -> Result a }

instance Monad Iter where
  return = Iter . Done
  (>>=) :: Iter a -> (a -> Iter b) -> Iter b
  (Iter iter0) >>= fiter = Iter $ \chunk -> continue (iter0 chunk)
    where continue :: Result a -> Result b
          continue (Done x rest)     = runIter (fiter x) rest
          continue (NeedInput iter1) = NeedInput (iter1 >>= fiter)
          continue (NeedIO ior)      = NeedIO (liftM continue ior)
          continue (Failed e)        = Failed e
```

This will give the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘b1’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b. Iter a -> (a -> Iter b) -> Iter b
    at Iteratee.hs:211:12
  ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      continue :: forall a1 b1. Result a1 -> Result b1
    at Iteratee.hs:214:23
  Expected type: Result b1
    Actual type: Result b
• In the expression: runIter (fiter x) rest
  In an equation for ‘continue’:
      continue (Done x rest) = runIter (fiter x) rest
  In an equation for ‘>>=’:
      (Iter iter0) >>= fiter
        = Iter $ \ chunk -> continue (iter0 chunk)
        where
            continue :: Result a -> Result b
            continue (Done x rest) = runIter (fiter x) rest
            continue (NeedInput iter1) = NeedInput (iter1 >>= fiter)
            continue (NeedIO ior) = NeedIO (liftM continue ior)
            continue (Failed e) = Failed e
• Relevant bindings include
    continue :: Result a1 -> Result b1 (bound at Iteratee.hs:215:11)
    fiter :: a -> Iter b (bound at Iteratee.hs:212:20)
    (>>=) :: Iter a -> (a -> Iter b) -> Iter b
      (bound at Iteratee.hs:212:3)
```

To add to my confusion, if I leave `continue` undefined but I assign a type the code compiles.

My guess is that this problem is caused by continue actually having type

```
continue :: forall a1 b1. Result a1 -> Result b1
```

hence the two `a`'s and `b`'s from the types above are actually different. But nevertheless, `continue` above must have a type. My question is then, which is the type of this function assigned by the compiler when the types are omitted.

*EDIT*:

If the `iter` parameter is explicitly passed then the code compiles:

```
instance Monad Iter where
  return = Iter . Done
  (>>=) :: Iter a -> (a -> Iter b) -> Iter b
  (Iter iter0) >>= fiter0 = Iter $ \chunk -> continue fiter0 (iter0 chunk)
    where continue :: (a -> Iter b) -> Result a -> Result b
          continue fiter (Done x rest)     = runIter (fiter x) rest
          continue fiter (NeedInput iter1) = NeedInput (iter1 >>= fiter)
          continue fiter (NeedIO ior)      = NeedIO (liftM (continue fiter) ior)
          continue _ (Failed e)        = Failed e
```

However I'd like to avoid having to pass the parameter explicitly, while being able to give `continue` a type.

Comment: Read up on [Scoped Type Variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In basic Haskell, every type signature is implicitly quantified universally

```
foo :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
foo b x y = bar y
   where bar :: a -> a
         bar y | b         = x
               | otherwise = y
```

actually means:

```
foo :: forall a. Bool -> a -> a -> a
foo b x y = bar y
   where bar :: forall a1. a1 -> a1
         bar y | b         = x
               | otherwise = y
```

and *fails* to compile since `x` is not of type `a1`.

Removing the type signature of `bar` makes it compile, and the compiler will associate to bar the correct type `a -> a` where `a` is NOT quantified universally. Note that this is a type that the compiler can infer, but that the user is prevented to write.

This is rather inconvenient!

So, the `ScopedTypeVarables` GHC extension circumvents that, allowing one to write

```
foo :: forall a. Bool -> a -> a -> a
foo b x y = bar y
   where bar :: a -> a
         bar y | b         = x
               | otherwise = y
```

and here the first `forall a.` makes `a` to be in scope in inner declarations. Further, the type of `bar` remains `a -> a` and is not universally quantified since `a` is now in scope. Hence, it compiles and the user was now able to write the wanted type annotation.

Comment: Just to emphasize, to trigger the use of the extension you *must* explicitly quantify.